# how to write Junit of methode indexOf()?

Tags: java, string, junit

How to write JUnit test that verifies if the method: int indexOf(String substring) of standard class String (java.lang.String) works corrrectly.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use JUnit's assertEquals method. It is common practice with the assertEquals method to have assertEquals(expected, actual). An example test is shown below:

```
import java.lang.*
public class Tests{
@test
public void indexOftest(){
    String str = "Java is fun"
    String characterWanted = "i"

    /*
    (J) (a) (v) (a) ( ) (i) (s) ( ) (f) (u) (n)
     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
    Therefore the index of i is 5.
    */

    actual = 5
    expected = str.indexOf(characterWanted)
    assertEquals(expected, actual)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers here.

Number one: you simply test it, meaning you think up testcases, that work like:

```
given a certain string X
when indexOf() is invoked with a certain parameter Y
then the expected outcome should be Z
```

Now you start thinking up sets of X,Y,Z data points and write down the tests.

Number two: you don't. There is no need or point in testing standard library methods; especially not such super basic things. You can safely assume that these methods all work correct, and that your tests will never uncover a problem.

The only good reason to do this would be to practice how to do it. And for that, use the other answer for a simple specific example, and then digest my answer to get to real "core" of such example based tests.